# Issue with langchain llm and huggingface. The SSL issue

Tags: py-langchain, large-language-model

I an getting an SSL when using huggingface hub when using langchain LLM. Below is the error. I tried options input my username and password and did not work.. please help
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api-inference.huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pipeline/text2text-generation/google/flan-t5-xl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)'))

PromptTemplate input